# Delete from two tables in one query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL

```
#messages table  : 
messageid
messagetitle 
.
.

#usersmessages table 
usersmessageid 
messageid
userid
.
.
```

Now if I want to delete from messages table it's ok. But when I delete message by messageid the record still exists on usersmessage and I have to delete from this two tables at once.

I used the following query :

```
DELETE FROM messages LEFT JOIN usersmessages USING(messageid) WHERE messageid='1' ;
```

Then I test

```
   DELETE FROM messages , usersmessages 
   WHERE messages.messageid = usersmessages.messageid 
   and messageid='1' ;
```

But these two queries are not accomplishing this task .

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Can't you just separate them by a semicolon?

```
Delete from messages where messageid = '1';
Delete from usersmessages where messageid = '1'
```

**OR**

Just use `INNER JOIN` as below

```
DELETE messages , usersmessages  FROM messages  INNER JOIN usersmessages  
WHERE messages.messageid= usersmessages.messageid and messages.messageid = '1'
```

Comment: what happen if i want to put this code in a loop ? i know i can put the semicolon absolutely .

Comment: It can be put in a loop. You can do it programmtically and send the message id as a parameter. As long as you don't keep on sending it the same id it won't do the delete over and over.

Comment: @Eric Yeah , i Test This Query it working perfectly ;) tanks . but i do the same query before i post but it's dosen't work because i don't say messages.messageid='1' i just say messageid='1' ; 
tanks any way .

Comment: @Eric i don't think it's good idea to create too queries to do simple task like this as long as i can do that in just one query .

Comment: @Mehdi I hear you. But is the second query I gave you the one that worked?

Comment: @Eric Yes . this query is what i need . the second query is working for me .

Comment: If you do this in two queries, you really should wrap this in a transaction. As for running delete queries in a loop, you are better off formulating a single query to do all the deletes.

Comment: Checkout another example of delete query with joins http://www.bennadel.com/blog/939-Using-A-SQL-JOIN-In-A-SQL-DELETE-Statement-Thanks-Pinal-Dave-.htm

Comment: Doesn't work with SQL Server: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I have no problems in SQL Server with the above statements. Please note that if you're using the first syntax, it's a semi-colon and not a comma.

Comment: @Eric could this be altered to allow for a row to be deleted in one table even if there are no associated rows in the second table?

Comment: @user2363025 - Yup, you could use a `left join`, but make sure that your `where` clause is very limiting first!! Make sure you try this as a `select` before attempting the `delete`. The `left join` will pull back *all* rows on the left (first) table unless you limit it in the `left join`.

Answer (score 56):

```
DELETE a.*, b.* 
FROM messages a 
LEFT JOIN usersmessages b 
ON b.messageid = a.messageid 
WHERE a.messageid = 1
```

translation: delete from table **messages** where messageid =1, if table **uersmessages** has messageid = messageid of table **messages**, delete that row of **uersmessages** table.

Comment: comment for all: as shown in this exemple, it is important to specify in which table the delete should work . Great post @angry_kiwi

Comment: I had just to change the order, FROM usersmessages b LEFT JOIN messages a

Answer (score 19):

You should either create a `FOREIGN KEY` with `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
ALTER TABLE usersmessages
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_usermessages_messageid
FOREIGN KEY (messageid)
REFERENCES messages (messageid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

, or do it using two queries in a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;;

DELETE
FROM    usermessages
WHERE   messageid = 1

DELETE
FROM    messages
WHERE   messageid = 1;

COMMIT;
```

Transaction affects only `InnoDB` tables, though.

Comment: You *can* delete from multiple tables in one query! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: yes you can! But to me...it's easier to do what my answer said.

Comment: I added the cascade on a similar table of mine. When I attempted to delete from 1 table only, it deleted the record and left the related one orphaned. What good is the constraint?

Comment: @barfoon: is your table `InnoDB`?

Comment: @Quassnoi Oops! I definitely thought it was, what a goof. All tables are MyISAM. Can I change all of them on the fly with data in them? Or is there issues with that?

Comment: @barfoon: yes you can but be aware that the `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL` indexes will not work in `InnoDB`.

Answer (score 9):

no need for JOINS:

```
DELETE m, um FROM messages m, usersmessages um

WHERE m.messageid = 1 

AND m.messageid = um.messageid
```

Comment: But this is still an implicit `CROSS JOIN`

Answer (score 9):

The OP is just missing the table aliases after the delete

```
DELETE t1, t2 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.id = some_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be more helpful if you try to explain why this would work and why the OPs solution didn't.

Comment: why would aliases be required?

Answer (score 7):

You have two options:

First, do two statements inside a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
  DELETE FROM messages WHERE messageid = 1;
  DELETE FROM usermessages WHERE messageid = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Or, you could have ON DELETE CASCADE set up with a foreign key.  This is the better approach.

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child (
  id INT, parent_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

You can read more about ON DELETE CASCADE [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
DELETE message.*, usersmessage.* from users, usersmessage WHERE message.messageid=usersmessage.messageid AND message.messageid='1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this please

```
DELETE FROM messages,usersmessages

USING messages

INNER JOIN usermessages on (messages.messageid = usersmessages.messageid)

WHERE messages.messsageid='1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
DELETE a.*, b.*  
FROM table1 as a, table2 as b  
WHERE a.id=[Your value here] and b.id=[Your value here]
```

I let `id` as a sample column.

Glad this helps. :)

Comment: So that asterikses (`*`) are rendered properly you need to indent the query with 4 spaces in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this, to delete particular value when both the columns having 2 or many of same column name.

```
DELETE project , create_test  FROM project INNER JOIN create_test
WHERE project.project_name='Trail' and  create_test.project_name ='Trail' and project.uid= create_test.uid = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

there's another way which is not mentioned here (I didn't fully test it's performance yet), you could set array for all tables -> rows you want to delete as below

```
// set your tables array
$array = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3'];


// loop through each table
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

 // get each single array
 $single_array = $array[$i];

 // build your query
 $query = "DELETE FROM $single_array WHERE id = 'id'";

 // prepare the query and get the connection
 $data = con::GetCon()->prepare($query);

 // execute the action
 $data->execute();
}
```

then you could redirect the user to the home page.

```
header('LOCATION:' . $home_page);
```

hope this will help someone :)

Thanks

Comment: This might well help someone... looks like PHP though, I don't think that's necessarily within the scope of the question :)