# MySQL delete from 2 tables with one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete from two tables, based on a query in one table

Table: entities
guid: integer
subtype: integer
time_created: integer  (Unix timestamp)

Table: objects_entity
guid: integer
title: text

guid in objects_entity is a foreign key to entities.guid

I need to delete related records in both tables based on subtype=17 and time_created is older than 14 days in entities  (so also delete related objects_entity)

I'm very bad at SQL and by looking at examples I've created this:

```
DELETE entities, objects_entity FROM entities a INNER JOIN objects_entity b on b.guid = a.guid AND a.subtype =17 AND a.time_created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY))
```

but this gives the error:

```
#1109 - Unknown table 'entities' in MULTI DELETE
```

which is beyond me, as a select statement identical to above works correctly.... The table exists.

Any ideas what's wrong with my syntax? Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete from two tables in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace

```
DELETE entities, objects_entity
```

with

```
DELETE a, b
```

since you are aliasing your tables with `a` and `b`.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
```

OR

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
USING table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
```