# Simply merge 2 Delete query to make it one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 delete SQL query i want to make it one.

```
$sql1= DELETE FROM user WHERE userid={$id}
```

another is

```
$sql = Delete FROM user_meta where userid = {$id}
```

Any suggestions? I want to make it simple.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL database in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way of deleting things from different tables "at the same time" is to wrap them in a transaction.  Something like:

```
begin transaction thedeletes
    DELETE FROM user WHERE userid={$id};
    DELETE FROM user_meta WHERE userid = {$id}
commit transaction thedeletes;
```

In MySQL you can actually put these in the same query:

```
delete u, um
    from user u join
         user_meta um
         on u.userid={$id} and um.userid = {$id};
```

Comment: Can you please update the query? . I dont have meta_key its just userid.

but i got the idea. Thank you so much .

Comment: Thank you! it worked! i was just wondering why you use only JOIN not INNER JOIN?

Comment: @user3201500: JOIN = INNER JOIN in most, if not all, SQL products. JOIN is shorter while INNER JOIN results in fewer questions.

Comment: DELETE FROM user, user_meta from user 
  INNER JOIN user_meta 
  WHERE user.userid=user_meta.userid 
  and user.userid=".$id.", i use this as query but it didnt work. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @user3201500 . . . Between the `delete` and the `from` are the tables needed for deletion.  Note that this query starts `delete u, um from . . .`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete from 2 tables in DELETE statement, but you issue 2 statements in 1 go:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM user WHERE userid={$id};
DELETE FROM user_meta WHERE meta_key = {$id};"
```