# Using the "UNION" Delete MySQLI Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to delete some informations of my database in 2 tables.

First question, is it possible ?
If yes:

I had tried a `UNION DELETE` query, but it doesn't work.

```
$delete = mysqli_query($sql, "(DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id LIKE '".$id."' && userid LIKE '".$userid."') UNION (DELETE FROM table2 WHERE source_id LIKE '".$id."' && userid LIKE '".$userid."')");
```

Comment: What do you intend to get by delete and union in one query? Why not using two separate delete statements?

Comment: I want to delete informations of 2 tables, i thought this can be realised with Union.

Comment: I think you can JOIN and delete... something like `DELETE tbl1, tbl2 FROM table1 as tbl1 JOIN table2 as tbl2 ON.......... WHERE id.tbl1 LIKE '".$id."' ...........`

Comment: No, simply, use two sequential delete statements. Also, I have just noticed &&. In mysql, you have to use AND operator instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UNION` is used only with `SELECT` statements:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

If you don't want to use two separate `DELETE` statements and those two tables are related, try using the `JOIN` statement:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
DELETE FROM 
    n.table1 INNER JOIN m.table2
WHERE 
    n.id = m.source 
  AND 
    n.userid = m.userid 
  AND  
    n.id LIKE '".$id."' 
  AND 
    n.userid LIKE '".$userid."'
```

Comment: wow...do you even understand what `n.table1 INNER JOIN m.table2` is gonna do here?? :)

Comment: @NoobEditor : I have not tested, but [it looks great while he is using mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233479/3444240)

Comment: even if it serves the purpose....i certainly would not recommend it...why go against the native usage of functions and features???

Comment: @NoobEditor : I use only separate `DELETE`s, but OP wants to do it in one query, so yes, I would't recommend it, but  there is a way to do it. Can you agree with it?:)

Comment: no..i wont....one should not blindly answer...answers should help others improve logic and best practice...not only just getting the solution.... *damn, i sound like a university professor* !! :p

Comment: @NoobEditor: [MySQL approves](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51339/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-notulysses)

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` ( *set operations* ), `JOINS` all these are used to *show* data, i.e., used with `SELECT`, when multiple tables are to be used to fetch data.

to `DELETE` or `UPDATE`, please use separate queries!!

In your case

```
$delete = mysqli_query($sql, "(DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id LIKE '".$id."' && userid LIKE '".$userid."'));

if($delete)
{
   $delete2 = mysqli_query($sql, "(DELETE FROM table2 WHERE source_id LIKE '".$id."' && userid LIKE '".$userid."')");
}
```

Comment: Okay Thank you. I'll make it so.

Comment: care to mark any of the answers accepted if it helped...??? helps denoting question as closed!! :)