# MySQLi- Delete field from multiple tables in same query

Tags: php

I am trying to do a simple delete from two tables, but the field names and values are the same for each query, so I am trying to combine the two into one query. Is it possible?

```
$results = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM `recent_keys`, `recent_queries` WHERE `expires` < '$now_ts'"); // not working
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete from two tables in one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't manipulate 2 different tables in one query. try executing 2 queries at once by seperating them with semicolon:

```
$results = $mysqli->multi_query("DELETE FROM `recent_keys` WHERE `expires` < '$now_ts';  DELETE FROM `recent_queries` WHERE `expires` < '$now_ts';");
```

Comment: Thank you! And I'm assuming doing it like this in one query would be faster than doing them both separately? (actually this query is not working...)

Comment: indeed. you only send the query to database once, hence increasing performance.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut this does not work with `mysqli->query`->`Performs a query against the database.`. You would have to use [`mysqi->multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)->`Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE k.*, q.* FROM recent_keys k JOIN recent_queries q ON k.expires = q.expires WHERE k.expires < '$now_ts'");
```