# What's wrong with this OleDbCommand?

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I'm trying to delete from two tables with only 1 query.

I've tried these:

```
 Dim cq As String = "delete c.*, sb.* from Table1 c 
                     left join Table2 sb on c.ID = sb.OrderID 
                     where c.ID=" & txtID2.Text & ""
```

but I get "*Record is deleted.*"

```
 Dim cq As String = "delete t1,t2 from Table1 as t1 
                     join Table2 as t2 on t2.OrderID = t1.ID 
                     where ID=" & txtID2.Text & ""
```

but I get "*Syntax error in from clause.*"

Kindly fix my code or teach me regarding this. I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233479/2638872

Comment: If the two tables have a referential integrity constraint (parent-child relationship), you can setup cascading deletes.  If you delete the parent, the children are automatically deleted.   It makes things much simpler and more robust.

Comment: @mrtig Yes, I have. My first attempt actually. Still the same error "Syntax error in FROM clause".

Comment: @SteveWellens Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I'm trying to experiment on this just to practice initially deleting with joins this way. :D

Comment: One other thing... by building the string from a web-based variable, you are wide open to SQL-injection... Use OleDbParameter() for your queries.

Comment: @DRapp no problem. It's a Window-based app but yes I would do that. Thanks!