# How to delete records from some sql tables at one time?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- ruleTBL: ruleid hostname
- policyruleTBL: ruleid policyid

In the ruleTBL, the hostname is unique and one hostname may have more than one ruleid.
I want to delete all the records in the two tables with one hostname. How should I write the statement?

For example, if these are the records in ruleTBL

```
 (ruleid = 1, hostname = 'news')
 (ruleid = 2, hostname = 'news')
```

and in policyruleTBL:

```
(ruleid = 1, policyid = 4)
(ruleid = 2, policyid = 5)
```

I want to delete all the records with one statement.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Print your sample data table. Your explanation is not understandable.

Comment: is it sure that the hostname is unique and not the ruleid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use multiple table delete statement

```
DELETE ruleTBL, policyruleTBL 
FROM ruleTBL
JOIN policyruleTBL ON ruleTBL.ruleid = policyruleTBL.ruleid
WHERE ruleTBL.ruleid=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 delete ruleTBL, policyruleTBL from ruleTBL inner join policyruleTBL where ruleTBL.ruleid=policyruleTBL.ruleid and ruleTBL.hostname="name";
```

Checkout this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query) it might lead you to your goal

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to understand.

Anyway, I think you are asking how to delete from multiple tables with a JOIN:

```
DELETE t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.rule_id = t2.rule_id
WHERE <some condition>
```

This will delete all records in both tables that would have been returned if you replaced DELETE with SELECT...