# MYSQL: Delete from tables with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys, laravel-5

I have 5 tables which are

Users

```
-id
-influencer_id
```

Influencers

```
-id
```

Categories

```
-catogory_id
-influencer_id
```

platforms

```
-influencer_id
-platform_id
```

tasks

```
-influencer_id
-task_id
```

I want to delete an influencer and also delete all records at once. How to do that?

Comment: If you have actual foreign keys setup on your database, you can specify that on delete have it remove foreign records.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query

Answer (score 0):

use ON DELETE CASCADE while creating tables. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT, 
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) 
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

First delete records from other tables. You can use following query:

```
DELETE FROM Users u
USING Influencers i
WHERE u.id = i.id;
```

You can do the same for other tables and then at last `DROP` the `Influencers` table.

```
DROP TABLE Influencers;
```