# deleting from two tables in one query mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to delete from two tables. I know I can use a join but I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query) suggesting I could just do it like this with a semicolon:

```
$query = "  DELETE from pupil_data WHERE pupil_id=$pupil_id;
            DELETE from pupil_conditions WHERE pupil_id=$pupil_id";
$bob = $conn->query($query);
```

This doesn't work. If I do each query on their own then its fine.

Why doesn't it work with the semicolon?

Comment: You need to fire it with a [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: thanks - easy when you know how!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$query = "  DELETE from pupil_data WHERE pupil_id=$pupil_id;
            DELETE from pupil_conditions WHERE pupil_id=$pupil_id";
$bob = $conn->multi_query($query);
```

Comment: I think some people just take pleasure in downvoting an answer, without asking questions or seeking clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your query doesn't delete from two tables in one query. There are two separate SQL queries.

Second, you don't need to run 2 queries in one function call. Run two separate queries in two separate function calls. That would be logical and save you a lot of trouble.

Third, never use `mysqli_multi_query()` for such a whim. This function's purpose is different. Everyone who ask you to use it, never used it in reality and have no idea how to use it properly, helping you to shoot yourself in the foot.

Fourth, you ought to use prepared statements, instead of banging a variable in the query directly.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE from pupil_data WHERE pupil_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$pupil_id);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE from pupil_conditions WHERE pupil_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$pupil_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

is the code you have to run.

Comment: How is that an answer? Just asking

Comment: _"Third, never use mysqli_multi_query() for such a whim. This function's purpose is different and everyone who ask you to use it, never used it in reality"_ Then why not explain why it's "wrong" to use it?

Comment: Well I did wonder if 2 queries was ugly. I did also state that I am interested in why my code didn't work. I take your point about it really being 2 queries. I use prepared statements generally. I thought your tone was a bit harsh though but do appreciate you taking the time. Why not say something about why you shouldn't use the multi_query...

Answer (score -1):

> DELETE table_1, table_2,... FROM table-refs    [WHERE conditions]
>   DELETE FROM table_1, table_2,... USING table-refs [WHERE conditions]

Here is the [reference](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-statement.aspx)