# hql query to delete records in two tables

Tags: hibernate, hql, hql-delete

> My query is.

```
Query query1 = session.createQuery(
                "DELETE Question, Answer FROM Question que LEFT JOIN Answer ans ON que.id=ans.questionId  WHERE que.quiz_type_id=:qtypeid");
        query1.setParameter("qtypeid", id);
        query1.executeUpdate();
```

> This Query is not working..Please help...

[question table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT0QN.png)

[answer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJU49.png)

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 38 [DELETE com.online.test.model.Question, Answer FROM com.online.test.model.Question que LEFT JOIN Answer ans ON que.id=ans.questionId WHERE que.quiz_type_id=:qtypeid]

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 38 [DELETE com.online.test.model.Question, Answer FROM com.online.test.model.Question que LEFT JOIN Answer ans ON que.id=ans.questionId WHERE que.quiz_type_id=:qtypeid]

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 38 [DELETE com.online.test.model.Question, Answer FROM com.online.test.model.Question que LEFT JOIN Answer ans ON que.id=ans.questionId  WHERE que.quiz_type_id=:qtypeid]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 38 [DELETE com.online.test.model.Question, Answer FROM com.online.test.model.Question que LEFT JOIN Answer ans ON que.id=ans.questionId  WHERE que.quiz_type_id=:qtypeid]
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    com.online.test.Dao.AdminTestDaoImpl.removeQuiz(AdminTestDaoImpl.java:104)
    com.online.test.service.AdminTestServicesImpl.removeQuiz(AdminTestServicesImpl.java:58)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.removeQuiz(Unknown Source)
    com.online.test.AdminController.removecountry(AdminController.java:59)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.9 logs.
Apache Tomcat/8.0.9

Comment: Can you please post some more details? Do you have an error? If so, what error?, ...

Comment: please post you error message and the setting parameter to qtypeid

Comment: "DELETE FROM Question que LEFT JOIN Answer ans ON que.id=ans.questionId  WHERE que.quiz_type_id=:qtypeid");

Comment: look into this... same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joins are not supported in Hibernate bulk DML operations. From the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html#batch-direct):

> No [Section 16.4, “Forms of join syntax”](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins-forms), either implicit or
>   explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be
>   used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain
>   joins.

You can use two `delete` statements to delete answers and questions separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `on` with `join` in the HQL. And you can't use `join` for delete, as @DraganBozanovic suggested. The valid query can be

```
DELETE FROM Question que WHERE que.quiz_type_id = :qtypeid
```

To delete answers when you delete a corresponding question you need to have annotation properties — `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, `orphanRemoval = true`

If you use one-to-many association  it can be

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Answer> answers;
```

Instead of using `CascadeType.ALL` you can consider to use more specifically cascade.