# SQL Deleting rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to delete the the same highest value from multiple tables, however I get a syntax error on t1 and t3. Any ideas how to fix it? Btw I'm using MS SQL (TSQL)

```
DELETE FROM ProductsOrders t1, Orders t2
    JOIN ( SELECT MAX(OrderID) FROM Orders) t3
WHERE t1.OrderID = t3.OrderID
AND t2.OrderID = t3.OrderID
```

Comment: why did you delete the answer?

Comment: I didn't delete the answer...

Comment: Even my edits have been gone. I guess it's the webpage either went on backup or something else...

Comment: not you, i was talking to @juergen

Comment: i've rolled back his changes

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query

Personally I find it a much better design to have a foreign key with a cascade on delete.

Comment: your answer was correct! And thank you, though in ms sql you cant delete from multiple tables. You have to use DELETE for every table

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete from multiple tables with one statement in T-SQL statement, with the exception of cascading deletes.

Here is a simple solution:

```
DECLARE @MaxOrderID INT

BEGIN TRAN

SELECT @MaxOrderID = Max(OrderID) FROM Orders

DELETE FROM ProductOrders WHERE OrderID = @MaxOrderID
DELETE FROM Orders WHERE OrderID = @MaxOrderID

COMMIT TRAN
```