# (er_parse_error) #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this 3 different ways for my delete. 
I would like to delete the row from table buylist_products if the conditions are ok.

try 1 :

```
DELETE FROM parkage_buylist_products bp, parkage_productsmeta pm, parkage_buylist b WHERE bp.product_id = pm.product_id AND (pm.meta_key = 'we_buy_price' OR pm.meta_key = 'we_buy_rule') AND pm.meta_value = 0 AND bp.order_id = b.order_id AND b.status = 'in_progress' AND b.order_id = 24
```

try 2 :

```
DELETE FROM parkage_buylist_products bp  
LEFT JOIN parkage_productsmeta pm, parkage_buylist b  
ON bp.product_id = pm.product_id 
WHERE (pm.meta_key = 'we_buy_price' OR pm.meta_key = 'we_buy_rule') 
AND pm.meta_value = 0 
AND bp.order_id = b.order_id 
AND b.status = 'in_progress' 
AND b.order_id = 24
```

try 3 :

```
DELETE FROM parkage_buylist_products bp, parkage_buylist b    
WHERE bp.order_id = b.order_id 
AND b.status = 'in_progress' 
AND b.order_id = 24 
AND bp.product_id IN (SELECT pm.product_id 
                  FROM parkage_productsmeta pm
                WHERE (pm.meta_key = 'we_buy_price' OR pm.meta_key = 'we_buy_rule') 
                AND pm.meta_value = 0
```

For the first one i have tried, delete bp, delete bp.* which it gives me an error on syntax.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: 1) What about the other 2 attempts? 2) Pls share the exact error message with us.

Comment: for the 3 attempts i have the same error : #1064. I am in phpMyAdmin it doesn not show more details

Comment: Yes, it does. phpmyadmin displays the full MySQL error message.

Comment: I'm not familiar with phpMyAdmin - do you need to change setting to get it to display / stop displaying message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix MySQL error #1064?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515347/how-can-i-fix-mysql-error-1064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
DELETE parkage_buylist_products,
       parkage_productsmeta,
       parkage_buylist
FROM parkage_buylist_products
JOIN parkage_productsmeta
JOIN parkage_buylist
WHERE parkage_buylist_products.product_id = parkage_productsmeta.product_id
  AND parkage_buylist_products.order_id = parkage_buylist.order_id
  AND ( parkage_productsmeta.meta_key = 'we_buy_price' OR
        parkage_productsmeta.meta_key = 'we_buy_rule' )
  AND parkage_productsmeta.meta_value = 0
  AND parkage_buylist.status = 'in_progress'
  AND parkage_buylist.order_id = 24;
```

After doing a quick search using the criteria `delete from many tables at once sql` I found the page at [delete from two tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query).  I took the second option from their most popular Answer (by Eric) and modified it with your code.

Based on my research, this should delete from the tables specified after `DELETE` those records that meet the criteria specified, which are the same as in your Question.  Please note that I have stripped the aliases away - I prefer working without them where I can.  Presumably you can still use them here.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: It does not like the elements after DELETE. I dont understand why. it says : Unexpected token. A question, would it delete the rows corresponding from the 3 tables?

Comment: Second version added.  Please try that.  (Sorry, but this is my first time trying to delete across multiple tables in one statement).

Comment: Oopsis, your thing is working very well thank you! I erased a letter on the pasting thing :/ Thank you very much

Comment: That is good to hear!  I have updated my Answer with an explanation.  Feel free to tick this Answer if it has suitably addressed your needs, and / or to ask any follow up questions you might have.