# How to use multiple table names in one delete query - Not all table have data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**What I need**

I have a database called dbtuts and it has total 7 tables.

Table names are tbl_uploads, variationtable1, variationtable2, variationtable3, variationtable4, variationtable5, variationtable6.

All these tables have a column called `prjId`.

I want to delete a row from tbl_uploads table and from variationtable1 to variationtable6 whereby prjId is lets say xxxx .

But the problem is variationtable1 to variationtable6 may or may not have this xxxx data for prjId column.

Is there any way whereby I can execute a single query that will delete xxxx if there is such a data.

**My Codes**

I tried to do the following way, but it is not working.

```
$deleteQuery = "
DELETE 
  FROM dbtuts.tbl_uploads
     , dbtuts.variationtable1
     , dbtuts.variationtable2
     , dbtuts.variationtable3
     , dbtuts.variationtable4
     , dbtuts.variationtable5
     , dbtuts.variationtable6 
 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx'
 ";

$resultDeleteQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$deleteQuery);
```

Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: Do all those tables mentioned in the delete statement have this column `prjId`?

Comment: Why not have one variationtable instead of 6?

Comment: @cdaiga Yes. All tables mentioned in the delete statement have this column prjId

Comment: @Strawberry All these tables have many data. That is why i separate it into 6 thinking that will be good. isn't it?

Comment: You can use foreign keys and `on cascade delete`, also you can use `DELETE ... JOIN`

Comment: [How to use multiple table names in one delete query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: @Anu No. If tables become large - something over a million rows, say, then look at partitioning the tables. Giorgos's answer is the best of the answers posted below, but possibly a poor choice when compared with proper partitioning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete from two tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a single query using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
DELETE t, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6
  FROM dbtuts.tbl_uploads t
  LEFT JOIN dbtuts.variationtable1 v1 ON t.prjId = v1.prjId
  LEFT JOIN dbtuts.variationtable2 v2 ON t.prjId = v2.prjId
  LEFT JOIN dbtuts.variationtable3 v3 ON t.prjId = v3.prjId
  LEFT JOIN dbtuts.variationtable4 v4 ON t.prjId = v4.prjId
  LEFT JOIN dbtuts.variationtable5 v5 ON t.prjId = v5.prjId
  LEFT JOIN dbtuts.variationtable6 v6 ON t.prjId = v6.prjId
WHERE t.prjId = 'xxxx'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/111556/2)

**Note:** This kind of query wouldn't be necessary if your database schema was properly designed. The correct way to implement this kind of funcionality is to create foreign keys in each of the `dbtuts.variationtablex` tables with `ON CASCADE DELETE`.

Comment: This perfectly works for me. I am new to mysql. Thus my data structuring may not be good. I didn't quite understand your codes though. I will try to get more grip about JOIN method in MySQL. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This would be the most easy way to do it and in 1 query

```
$deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM dbtuts.tbl_uploads WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable1 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable2 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable3 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable4 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable5 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable6 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx'";
```

Please remember to use prepared statements when you execute this query so you prevent your project against sql injection - Thanks to Strawberry for mentioning
You could do it like this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM dbtuts.tbl_uploads WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                          DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable1 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                          DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable2 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                          DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable3 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                          DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable4 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                          DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable5 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx';
                          DELETE FROM dbtuts.variationtable6 WHERE prjId = 'xxxx'";);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: This answer is more complete than mine, and was here first. This will work nicely.

Comment: I would be concerned with security with a multiquery approach.

Comment: @Strawberry I only posted the query here, I never mentioned anything about sql injection

Comment: Which is why I'm bringing it up.

Comment: @Strawberry Added it in my answer

Comment: @Strawberry Since you raised the concern of SQL injection, is there any better way to do this in one query?

Comment: Better, but this isn't the right way to prepare against injection.

Comment: Does this answer work for you otherwise I delete it @Anu

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: @Ende I don't know why it is not working for me. The data still there even after I used your query. Anyway I got another answer which is working. Thanks for your effort to help

Comment: No problem :)  Good luck with the rest