# [SQL]How to delete all rows containing NULL value on the joined table column using LEFT JOIN and DELETE

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, sql-delete

I am trying to get rid of every row that has no relation to the other table.

This is what I tried:

```
DELETE obj FROM objednavky obj 
    LEFT JOIN polozky_objednavek poObj
            ON poObj.objednavka_id = obj.id
            WHERE poObj.objednavka_id = null
```

Comment: `WHERE poObj.objednavka_id IS null` don't use `=` to compare aginst NULL.

Comment: @forpas genius, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE obj FROM objednavky obj 
    LEFT JOIN polozky_objednavek poObj
            ON poObj.objednavka_id = obj.id
            WHERE poObj.objednavka_id IS null
```

thanks to @forpas for comenting, I just needed to change:

```
item = NULL
```

to

```
item IS NULL
```

and worked itexactly as I needed. Keep in mind that SQL doesn't support this type of comparison.

Answer (score 0):

DELETE is only working on one table, so it should not be joined.  you can use the other table in your WHERE clause though, like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM objednavky obj 
  WHERE( SELECT objednavka_id FROM polozky_objednavek WHERE objednavka_id=objednavky.id) IS NULL
```

If you're doing this manually I recommend running the SELECT clause first (or at least a COUNT variant) to check you're not going to accidentally wipe out the entire table.

Comment: You absolutely can join other tables in a `DELETE` statement. OP's syntax looks good, apart from using `= NULL` instead of `IS NULL`

Comment: @cf_en - you may have misunderstood my comment, which I admit was not clear.  I didn't say you can't join for a delete, only that you shouldn't.  Who says you shouldn't is a valid question. Including the other tables in the join can make it appear to someone that the intent is to delete from multiple tables .. so not joining makes the code clearer (in my opinion - I recognise other opinions are available!)

Comment: That's a fair comment. I've read opinion pieces that say you shouldn't join tables in `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements. Personally I think it's OK, it's useful sometimes for filtering and targeting the records to delete or update. Apparently MySql also allows you to delete from multiple tables in a single statement, which seems confusing and potentially dangerous.

Comment: @cf_en - so perhaps another reason why you *shouldn't* do it?

Comment: @RobLambden DELETE statement is absolutely working for 2 and more tables
check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233479/11776868

Comment: @Blue Print - as per my comments above I haven't said this doesn't work ... only that (in my opinion) it's clearer not to write statements that intend to only delete from one table with tables that are JOINed.  I believe that the SQL standard stipulates that DELETE should not delete from tables that are JOINed (although I believe you can use DELETE t1.*, t2.* FROM ....)  although different implementations may support 'cascade deletes' or an expression that deletes from multiple tables as cf_en has suggested.  My comment was about making the intent of the statement clear.

Comment: @RobLambden Oh, then it was a misunderstanding. I think you missed what you sayed in your first sentence, you state: "DELETE is only working on one table, so it should not be joined." - that is equivalent  to : "DELETE is not working on more than one table, so it should not be joined." I am not reffering to the fact if it is better to use JOIN or SELECT.

Comment: Personally I prefer to `JOIN` tables into a `DELETE` statement than to use subqueries in the `WHERE` clause to apply filtering/targeting for the delete. The intent should be clear to anyone with a basic knowledge of SQL. Targeting two tables for a `DELETE`, though, goes too far :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`.
Try this:

```sql
DELETE FROM objednavky obj
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
          *
      FROM
          polozky_objednavek poObj
      WHERE
           `poObj`.`objednavka_id` = `obj`.`id`);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58922b/6)

Comment: It says this:  #1054 - Unknown column 'obj.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Is `id` column exists on `objednavky` table?

Comment: @BluePrint Can you try run the query again? I updated my answer.

Comment: Glad to hear. I just added the `backticks` around column names. You can accept the answer if you think it was helpful :)

Comment: I would, but it is not really answering my question; "using JOIN and DELETE"

Comment: I think It does what you need to do.