# How to delete multiple tables in parallel

Tags: python, mysql, sql, amazon-emr

I am performing bulk delete for multiple tables around 20. But right now they are in sequence (one by one). So they are taking time.  Can i do bulk delete in parallel by using python or Mysql. They are all independent tables. Any suggestions please. I am running my code in AWS EMR

```
delete from table1;
delete from table2;
delete from table3;
```

Comment: Does this help you out? https://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-delete-data/

Comment: As I see you delete all rows. Use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE.

Comment: @Akina yes that is one of the option we are planning.

Comment: @cbracketdash We are running our code from python only. It is just how can i delete multiple statement in parallel.

Comment: If your connector allows multi-query then put all queries into one multiquery and execute it.

Comment: please check it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a solution for deleting tables in parallel but I believe it is possible to use parallelism to delete tables using the `MAXDOP` query option parameter.

```
-- DOPMAX stands for Degrees of Parallelism Maximum
delete from table1 option (DOPMAX 4);
delete from table2 option (DOPMAX 8);
delete from table3 option (DOPMAX 0); -- 0 means use all cpu's available
```

You can read more about this, through microsoft's [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks @Max Collier  I will look into it. , but i think my requirement is more I/O bound based rather then CPU bound.

Comment: The question is MySQL-tagged, the solution for SQL Server cannot be applied to it.