# MySQL delete row from at least one table using one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: one contains user logins and the other contains user data. I would like to delete users who may or may not exist in the latter table but definitely exist in the former. How do I account for users who may or may not exist? Please note that it should be in one query....
I have tried:

```
DELETE houses,houseusers FROM houses INNER JOIN houseusers ON houseusers.username = houses.username WHERE houses.username='user1' OR houseusers.username='user1';
```

Comment: It can be done in 1 query. Check this possible duplicate question [Delete from two tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233451/delete-from-two-tables-in-one-query/5126239)

Comment: @ErrBon I don't think this is a duplicate since I am asking about deleting from at least one table if a row does not exist in the second table. The question you have linked talks about deleting from exactly two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM houses WHERE username='user1';
DELETE FROM houseusers WHERE username='user1';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why would you need it to be in one query? Explain why this is a requirement.

Comment: It is a query to be run on a jdbc prepared statement and the number of affected rows needs to be known.

Comment: So run two statements. Retrieve the return value, the rows affected by each statement. Add those two numbers together.

Comment: Ok..I'll try it in the morning and tell you. Where I am it is very late.

Comment: To be clear, I mean run two prepared statements. You can't run two SQL statements in a single call to a prepared statement. Okay, good luck tomorrow.

Comment: This did the trick but it would be great if it was reduced to one query. Perhaps use of 1 query is cleaner.