# To delete multiple data from other tables do i have create delete file for every table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, crud

I am stuck at deleting data from my table ! I am deleting data from the table but I if i have to delete rows from multiple rows from another table ! Do i have to create multiple **delete** files for every table ???

I have not tried any other theory because i am stuck here in this problem

Comment: You can delete multiple rows in 1 table with 1 query, for deleting from multiple table at once, Is it what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233479/6934036

Comment: not clear. - what for example is a delete file?

Comment: Please give us some real world examples. If the data is related (referencing each other), then you should use foreign keys where you can have cascading deletes etc. However, you haven't given us enough info what it is/how it's set up so we can't really give a proper suggestion.